# Does a uniformly bounded sequence converge uniformly if it is already pointwisely convergent?

Tags: real-analysis

$\forall x$, $\exists M>0$ such that $|f(x,y)|<M$. Moreover $\mathop{\lim}_{y\to\infty}f(x,y)=1$ for each fixed $x$. Then can one say that $f(x,y)\to 1$ uniformly as $y\to\infty$? Why? If not, what additional conditions are needed?

Comment: No, uniform convergence doesn't follow (in general). What is the domain of $x$? (The answer to the last question depends on that.)

Comment: Uniform convergence in this case means that for any $\varepsilon >0$, there is a $Y$ such that $|1-f(x,y)|<\varepsilon$ for all $x$ and all $y>Y$.

Answer (score 0):

Define $f:(0,1]\times (0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ 
$$f(x,y) = x^{\frac{1}{y}}.$$

For each fixed $x$, we have $\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} f(x,y) = x^0 = 1$ . And the convergence is not uniform, for each $0< \epsilon < 1 $ and $y$, take $x = \epsilon^y$ we get 
$$f(x) = (\epsilon^y)^\frac{1}{y} = \epsilon < 1.$$

Even if the domain of $x$ is a compact interval $[0,1]$, we still wouldn't get uniform convergence, just take the function above and define $f(0,y) = 1$.

A sufficient condition to get uniform convergence would be:

1. the domain of $x$ is compact; and
2. the family of functions $\{f(\cdot,y)\}_{y\in(0,\infty)}$ is equicontinuous on the compact domain.

**Proof:** Let $\epsilon >0$ be given, from equicontinuity, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such
 that
$$|f(x_1,y) - f(x_2,y)| <\epsilon/2 \text{ for each } y \;\;\text{ whenever } |x_1-x_2| <\delta.$$
Cover the compact domain of $x$ with open balls of radius $\delta$, then there exists a finite subcover and let us label the centers $\{x_1, x_2,...x_n\}$. For each $x_i$, there exists a $Y_i\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $y\geq Y_i$, we have 
$$|f(x_i,y) - 1|\leq\epsilon/2.$$
Define $Y = \max_{1\leq i\leq n} Y_i$, and we see that for each $x$ in the domain (say $x\in B_\delta({x_i})$) and $y\geq Y$, we have
$$|f(x,y) - 1| \leq |f(x,y) - f(x_i,y) +f(x_i,y) - 1| \leq \\ \leq|f(x,y) - f(x_i,y)| + |f(x_i,y) - 1| \leq \epsilon/2 +\epsilon/2.$$